# Is there a way to handle cast type varchar and INT in age range SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm writing a query to calculate a range of age, I've age data in a string like '21', '31' etc. so I use `CAST(age AS INT)` to convert age into an integer but for some cases the age is given as 'NA' and in that case my `CAST(age AS INT)` fails as 'NA' can not be converted into an integer with the error

> Invalid input syntax for integer

Is there a way to handle that case?

```
SELECT 
    'Under 10' AS Age, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(age AS INT) < 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS People
FROM 
    people
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    '11-20', SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(age AS INT) BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM 
    people
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    '21-30', SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(age AS INT) BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM 
    people;
```

Comment: . . I removed the  inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `where` clause for this query, not conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 'Under 10' as Age, COUNT(*) as People
FROM people
WHERE age < 10
UNION ALL
SELECT '11-20', COUNT(*)
FROM people
WHERE age BETWEEN 11 AND 20
UNION ALL
SELECT '21-30', COUNT(*)
FROM people
WHERE age BETWEEN 21 AND 30;
```

Because of the type conversion rules in SQL, `age` will be convert to a number for the comparisons.  This is *implicit* conversion, which I don't like.  How you do the conversion explicitly and conveniently depends on the database.  For instance

- Postgres:  `age::int`
- MySQL:     `(age + 0)`

Worse than implicit comparison is using the wrong data type.  `age` should be a number, so you should fix the data:

```
alter table people alter column age int;
```

And, `age` generally should not be in the database at all!  If changes from day to day.  Date of birth or birth year is more appropriate.

EDIT:

Given the presence of `'NA'` (which should really be `NULL`), I would recommend:

You would use `where` clause for this query, not conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 'Under 10' as Age, COUNT(*) as People
FROM people
WHERE NULLIF(age, 'NA')::int < 10
UNION ALL
SELECT '11-20', COUNT(*)
FROM people
WHERE NULLIF(age, 'NA')::int BETWEEN 11 AND 20
UNION ALL
SELECT '21-30', COUNT(*)
FROM people
WHERE NULLIF(age, 'NA')::int BETWEEN 21 AND 30;
```

Or, better yet, fix the data!

```
update people
    set age = NULL
    where age = 'NA';

alter table people alter column age int;
```

Comment: thanks, but here's the issue when i cast age to int it fails in case when age is "NA" and I also want the count where age is 'NA'
`
        SELECT  
       '0-10' as age, COUNT(*) as total 
          from age 
         WHERE age::int < 10
`

Comment: and I can't convert the age data type in the table as there are some people which have  'NA' in it which i need to count as well

Comment: You should replace `'NA'` with `NULL` and use numbers for the value.